# JS Base 64 decode - java encode

Tags: javascript, java, base64

I have a string **S**, which I decode (Base 64) in js and send to java server.
Server needs to encode (Base 64) input.
The problem is that original input string  **S** which I have in js before manipulations differs from encoded in java.
The encoding is "windows-1252".

In java I use java.util.Base64.

```
Base64.getEncoder().encode(str.getBytes("windows-1252"))
```

Lengths of original and encoded strings are equal, and most of chars are equal too, but some differs.

Original string is

```
"7y4+R/oWOGRo6vaV7k6uvVase5ial/E9L51gYfyhXys="
```

decoded is

```
"ï.>Gú8dhêöîN®½V¬{ñ=/`aü¡_+"
```

and in java I have

```
"7y4+R/oWOGRo6vY/7k6uvVasez8/P/E9Lz9gYfyhXys="
```

Is there any way to get the original string in java?

In js I used

```
 function decode64(input) {
    var output = "";
     var chr1, chr2, chr3 = "";
     var enc1, enc2, enc3, enc4 = "";
     var i = 0;
     var base64test = /[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g;
     if (base64test.exec(input)) {
        alert("There were invalid base64 characters in the input text.\n" +
              "Valid base64 characters are A-Z, a-z, 0-9, '+', '/',and '='\n" +
              "Expect errors in decoding.");
     }
     input = input.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9\+\/\=]/g, "");
     do {
        enc1 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc2 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc3 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        enc4 = keyStr.indexOf(input.charAt(i++));
        chr1 = (enc1 << 2) | (enc2 >> 4);
        chr2 = ((enc2 & 15) << 4) | (enc3 >> 2);
        chr3 = ((enc3 & 3) << 6) | enc4;
        output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr1);
        if (enc3 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr2);
        }

        if (enc4 != 64) {
           output = output + String.fromCharCode(chr3);
        }

        chr1 = chr2 = chr3 = "";
        enc1 = enc2 = enc3 = enc4 = "";

     } while (i < input.length);
        return unescape(output);
  }
```

Comment: My guess: Your assumption the string is  "windows-1252" encoded is wrong. please provide the actual input string.

Comment: @TimothyTruckle, I've added a decoded string in question. The problem is that windows-1252 is the most similar encoding, which returns something alike original input.

UPD. You may be right. It looks like its ISO-8859-1

Comment: Why decode a base 64 in JS and send as binary to Java server and encode again? Send the base64 string both should be the same.